# Grabbing a specific list from the DOM, while ignoring another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a simple script that grabs a random list item from an unordered list and assigns a variable to it for display as shown here:

```
var list = $("ul li").toArray();
var elemlength = list.length;
   console.log(list); //for debugging
var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*elemlength);
var randomitem = list[randomnum];
     $(randomitem).css({"display": "block", "list-style-type": "none"});
```

the list is wrapped around the id #list-feed, so something like:

```
<ul id="list-feed">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, I have an other list I used in my navigation earlier in the HTML inside my header element.  Therefore, this code grabs the list items from both this list and the list in my header.  Can I manipulate the code (assuming in my array build) that only uses the array in the list-feed id?

Something like?

```
var list = $("#list-feed ul li").toArray();
```

I know this doesn't work sensibly or programmatically, but I am new to jQuery concepts, and DOM manipulation, so wanted to know a good answer for how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using jQuery please add the tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just do:

```
var list = $("#list-feed li").toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your js doesn't work because it's attempting to select a UL within #list-feed. #list-feed doesn't contain any ULs - it IS a UL. #list-feed has only LIs, which is why j08691's suggestion works.